# wake on lan to wake up laptop from android phones

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, network-programming

i heard that wol(wake on lan) will only work for desktop systems. is there any implementation in java for wol, so that it works for laptops?(wol is the mechanism of turning on the remote system by sending 'magic packet' to the system).and is there any implementation in java for android phones? i found a simple wol apps in android market, i tried to extract the functionality of these apps, by practically testing them. but no app is working for both desktop and laptop systems.i configured my windows pc, so that it allows magic packet to wake on the pc.but i dont know where its going wrong.

Comment: Are you asking for some Java code that sends the magic WOL packets?

Comment: hey, i need to know whether it works for laptops(i need to switch these laptops from my android phone). if possible please put some sample codes for this mechanism

Answer (score 2):

WOL is a BIOS setting that you will need to turn on on the individual machines (I think it is turned off by default). I don't think there is any reason that laptops cannot accept WOL packets.

Here is a simple implmentation of WOL for Java: http://www.jibble.org/wake-on-lan/
It should be easy to port it over to work on Android.

However, you have to note that WOL will only work within a LAN and that the target machines have to be in a specific power setting in order to allow them to turn on.

Comment: is there any implementation for WOL

Comment: There is a link in my answer to an implementation of WOL for Java.

Comment: is there any implementation for WOW(Wake on Wan)??

Comment: I am pretty sure sending a wake up packet over the Internet (WOW) is not possible. Otherwise you would be able to turn on anyone's computer whenever you wanted.

Comment: No, it's definitely possible.  I do it all the time.  You just have to set up your router to forward port 9 to the computer that you want to wake up.

Comment: I know that this is old now and probably won't interest the OP, but I thought I might add this: The app Unified Remote (http://www.unifiedremote.com/) appears to have WoL built into it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific. If your laptop is connected over WiFi then there are big chances that it won't work. If your laptop is connected over an Ethernet cable then most probably it will work. You just have to enable WOL from the BIOS, or on some devices it can be also done from the network interface properties.
I'm using [WolOn](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitklog.wolon&utm_source=stackovf) Android app to wake a laptop connected over cable and it works flawlessly both on Windows and Ubuntu.